# What does "dirt" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

From the movie [Goodfellas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodfellas):

A woman shows her two friends her new home.

> Woman: Four and a half months of **dirt**.
>
> One of her friends: It's so good.
>
> Woman: I did it. Do you love it?
>
> Her friend: Oh it's beautiful.

It seems "dirt" possibly means "hard work", but it doesn't have such a definition in dictionaries. The closest definition is "filth". Is "dirt" here a slang usage?

Comment: Dirt in these contexts is usually information collected on a person, which can be used for blackmailing them. One collects dirt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what the meaning might be without a proper clip showing the full context.  While @Lambie is right that "***dirt***" in a gangster movie usually means *compromising information*, I think in this context it simply means *struggle and inconvenience* and could have been rephrased as

> Four and a half months of *construction site*

since it seems to be a new house that's being shown.  The dialogue goes on to point out various accoutrements within the house that are noteworthy.

Comment: +1 The snippet of dialog included in the question is actually everything there is. It is the start of a new scene, so there is nothing before the line with "dirt". And what follows, as you have said, is some bells and whistles of the house.

Comment: Then, the house has been under construction for four months.

Comment: Yes, as in "I had to put up with four and a half months of dirt (and filth and dust and irritation) to get this" which may not seem long, but if you *are* essentially the construction company (the mob) can be forever especially for the wife.

Comment: These types of things used to be called:  You hadda be there. Cheers.